# Is function application itself a function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, notation

Is function application itself a function? So given a function $f$ and an element $x$ we can define the function that takes $f$ and it's element $x$ to the value of $f$ at $x$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's a function that takes as input $f$ and $x$ and outputs $f(x)$. This can take some getting used to when you first see it. In some contexts it would be called a "higher-order function."

Comment: You have two different functions here, no infinite regression. One function is $f:A\to B$, the other is $\varphi: \operatorname{Func}(A,B)\times A\to B$, where $ \varphi(f,x)=f(x)$. Nothing necessarily infinite going on.

Comment: It seems real important to note that there is not one, single function that encompasses all instances of function application. For each pair of sets $A$ and $B$ there is a function corresponding to "function application", with a domain of $Func(A,B)\times A$, as defined by @Vercassivelaunos.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan about this notation '$f(x)$ is this defined for any function $f$ even if we aren't using the 'application' function, i.e. it's not any short-hand for $f¬x$ or some other binary operation that could be the 'application' function? Like $Mx=M\times x$

Comment: @user37577: I don't understand the question. It is a binary operation in the sense that it has two inputs. Those inputs are a function $f$ and an input to that function $x$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I apologise, multiplication is a binary function like 'application', and can be denoted by $a \times b$, can be written as $a(b)$, I'm asking if $f(x)$ is a shorthand for the 'application' function on $f$ and $x$, or if $f(x)$ has nothing to do with this function just that $apply$ maps to it?

Comment: Yes, you can consider it shorthand for function application. In some contexts you want to name function application explicitly because you want to manipulate it as a function; the name I like is $\text{eval}$ but other names are possible and different standards are likely common in different fields.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan does that make $apply(f,x)$ applying to 'apply' and so on?

Comment: Yes, $\text{apply}(f, x)$ is itself a function application, applying the function $\text{apply}$ to its inputs $f, x$. Fun stuff, huh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [definition of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) from $X$ to $Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ such that for every $x\in X$ there is a unique element of $Y$, called $f(x)$, such that the pair $(x,f(x)$ belongs in the subset of $X\times Y$ that defines the function. In simpler terms, every input has exactly one output (but different inputs may have the same output).

Let $Y^X$ denote the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ (as an aside, the notation is justified by setting $X=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $Y=\{1,\dots,m\}$ ; then $Y^X$ has  $m^n$ elements).

The evaluation map, sometimes denoted by $Ev$, is then defined as a map from $Y^X \times X \to Y$, mapping the pair $(f,x)\mapsto f(x)$, where $f\in Y^X$, $x\in X$, $f(x)\in Y$. It is then a straightforward exercise on the definitions to check that the evaluation map is a function from $Y^X \times X$ to $Y$; given a pair $(f,x)$ of a function $f:X\to Y$ and an element $x\in X$ there exists a unique element $y\in Y$ (namely $f(x)$) such that $\big((f,x),y\big)\in Ev\subset \big(Y^X\times X)\times Y$. This is true precisely because $f$ is a function.

Comment: user37577: To give a simple example of an evaluation map/function without clothing it in a lot of mathematical symbolism, consider the $2$-variable function $F(u,v)$ in which $u$ ranges over the set of polynomials (with real number coefficients) and $v$ ranges over the set of real numbers, and whose output is the input polynomial evaluated at the input real number.  Thus, when $u$ is the polynomial $3x^2 - 2x + 1$ and $v$ is the number $5,$ then $F(u,v)$ is the number $3(5)^2-2(5)+1=66.$

Comment: If we wanted to explicitly express the value of the apply function it is $apply(f,x)=f(x)$, $f(x)$ is in no way a shorthand for this function? Otherwise we'd be in an infinite loop of apply functions to express the value of the other apply function.

Comment: @user37577 It is not a loop. $f$ is a subset of $X\times Y$. The evaluation map $Ev$ is a subset of $(Y^X\times X)\times Y$. These are two distinct objects. If $g:X\to Y$ is another function, $Ev:(g,x)\mapsto g(x)$. You don't need $Ev$ in order to apply $f$, it is simply another function, taking any pair $(h,p)$ to $h(p)$.

Comment: So for any function $f(x)$ is it's value at $x$ so our 'application' function is just function that maps the functions and the input to final value, where we usually have decided on the function so we just compute it to $f(x)$, Makes sense, I had it in my head that somehow $f(x)$ was equivalent to $f¬x$ where $¬$ apply function.

Comment: @user37577 exactly

Comment: @user37577: I'm curious why my explanation didn't clear things up, as I can't think of a simpler explanation than what I gave above -- you input a polynomial and a number, and the (unique, for those inputs) output is the polynomial evaluated at that number. In trying to figure out what is the essence of your concern, I think (now) that your concern is how to correctly formulate this straightforward notion in a logical-math symbolic way.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It did, thank you, my only concern now is purely about the notation of it all, and the nature of some of the notations.